# need to update the item in the list

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a list called revision. It has a columns called wbscode and revisionnumber. Wbscode contains code of the project(eg.pcode1) and revisionnumber is to store revision number done for the pcode. Initially revisionnumber is to be set to 1 for pcode for 1st revision. Next time when I do revision for same wbscode(pcode) I need to update the revisionnumber as 2..SO ON.. I am doing it using javascript. Please help me

Comment: Have you tried simply enabling major Versions on the list? This'll store each version in the list separately, and the major version number should be available in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You could find details about how to handle operations with JavaScript against SharePoint 2013 lists and libraries in the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx

In this section, you have specifically a script that updates an item on a list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemCRUD

You need to retrieve the item you would like to update, then you could modify the item's properties by:

`oListItem.set_item('revisionnumber', '3');`

Finally, update the item by:

`oListItem.update();`